# find filter using arbitrary expression or command

Tags: shell, find

### Problem:

**Print the set of files (paths) that satisfy an arbitrary condition expressed as a shell expression using `find` command or an alternative.**

**Ex:** There's a certificate file called ca.crt whose OU (Organizational Unit) could be openshift, the following expression results a return status code of 0 if true and not 0 otherwise.

```bsh
openssl x509 -in ca.crt -text -noout 2>/dev/null | grep "OU = openshift" > /dev/null
```

How can I use this expression along with the `find` command to find all the certificate files whose Organizational Unit is 'openshift' under a given directory tree?

### I have looked at:

the `-exec` option from `find`'s `man` page and it states the following,

```
-exec command ;
              Execute command; true if 0 status is returned....
```

and I don't understand this particular statement: "true if 0 status is returned". Does that mean that `find` considers a file a match (true`) if the command execution for the particular file returned 0 status? Can this be any use of for solving the problem?

### Question:

What would be easiest way to do that without writing a shell script? One liner would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we want to do here is to use a pipeline with `-exec` in `find` as a test, i.e. something like

```bsh
find /search/path -type f -name ca.crt -exec something {} \; -print
```

where `something` returns an exit status of zero if the pathname should be printed.

Now, we can't make `find` use  a pipeline directly, but we can make it call `sh -c`:

```bsh
find /search/path -type f -name ca.crt -exec sh -c '
    openssl x509 -in "$1" -text -noout 2>/dev/null |
    grep -F -q "OU=openshift"' sh {} \; -print
```

What happens here is that `find` calls an in-line `sh -c` script to execute your pipeline (which I have changed only slightly).  If the pipeline exit with a zero exit-status, which it will do if `grep -q` finds the text pattern in the output from `openssl`, then `-print` takes effect and the pathname of the regular file with the name `ca.crt` is printed.

The pathname of the `ca.crt` file is passed in to the in-line script as `$1`.

---

In general, most predicates that you use with `find` are *tests*, including `-exec`.  If a test *passes* for a particular pathname, then the next test is considered.

In the command above, the tests are "is the file a regular file?" (`-type f`), "is its name `ca.crt`?" (`-name ca.crt`), "if I run this command now, with `{}` replaced by the pathname, is the exit status zero?" (`-exec ... \;`).  The `-print` at the end is always *true*, so any further test after that would always be carried out if `-print` is carried out.

---

You could make it ever so slightly more efficient by calling the `sh -c` script for as many pathnames at once as possible, instead of once per pathname.  We then do the printing of the pathnames from within the in-line script.

```bsh
find /search/path -type f -name ca.crt -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if openssl x509 -in "$pathname" -text -noout 2>/dev/null |
            grep -F -q "OU=openshift"
        then
            printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

This is how to correctly feed a loop with pathnames from `find`.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: never knew most predicates including actions were tests. So exec is an action and a test.

Comment: @IreshDissanayaka ... or a test with possible side-effects (depending on what the command that you execute via `-exec` does).  It depends on how you see it.

Comment: -exec sh -c '
    openssl x509 -in "$1" -text -noout 2>/dev/null |
    grep -F -q "OU=openshift"' sh {} \;     Here why is 'sh' passed as an argument? Is it needed?

Comment: @IreshDissanayaka The `sh` at the end gets place in `$0` inside the in-line script.  This string would get used in any error messages that the `sh -c` script may produce (to identify to the user where the error is coming from). The string is arbitrary, but it's is customary to use the command's name.